# ArcMap calculating driving distance without Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance

I'm using ArcMap 10.8. I need to find areas that are within 150 km driving distance of certain cities. Generate Service Areas with the Network Analyst extension seems to be capable of this, but I don't have the required license for it.

Is there a way to do this without Network Analyst?

Comment: Do you truly need driving distances along highways? This is a much easier problem if not.  You don't need a special license to build a Route for each highway but you would need to have some measured distances for the routes. Perhaps a state highway Web service?

Comment: @danak I'm not sure I fully understand the question of if I need the driving distances? The purpose of my exercise is to find out if certain properties are within a possible day's drive (thus, the 150 km). Does this clarify your question?